# Mailchimp api v3 : Batch subscription always pending

Tags: php, mailchimp, php-curl

I've been trying the mailchimp API in it's v3. Since I used php I had some trouble to start but now quite everything goes well.

I'm trying to add multiple subscribers to my list, in one go.

I looked there : https://devs.mailchimp.com/blog/batch-operations-and-put-in-api-v3-0/

and tried the following code :

```
<?php

$apiKey = "apikey";
$listId = "listid";

$memberId = md5(strtolower("mymail@gmail.com"));
$dataCenter = substr($apiKey,strpos($apiKey,'-')+1);
$url = 'https://'. $dataCenter . '.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/' . $listId .'/members';
$batchurl = 'https://'. $dataCenter . '.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/batches';
$filename = "test_csv.csv";
$handle = fopen($filename, "r");
$contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
fclose($handle);
$user_info = str_getcsv($contents, ";");
$ch = curl_init($batchurl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'apikey:'.$apiKey);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
$array = array();
for ($i = 1; $user_info[$i]; $i++) {

    $array[] = array(

            "method" => "PUT",
            "path" => 'lists/'.$listId.'members/'.md5(trim($user_info[$i])),
            "body" => '{"email_address" => '.trim($user_info[$i]).',"status" => "subscribed"}'
        );
}
$bck = '{"operations": '.json_encode($array).'}' ;

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $bck);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
var_dump($result);
```

Yet sadly, this code returns no error. Only :

```
string(624) "{"id":"af07a55fea","status":"pending","total_operations":0,"finished_operations":0,"errored_operations":0,"submitted_at":"2016-05-09T14:46:21+00:00","completed_at":"","response_body_url":"","_links":[{"rel":"parent","href":"https://us13.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/batches","method":"GET","targetSchema":"https://us13.api.mailchimp.com/schema/3.0/Batches/Collection.json","schema":"https://us13.api.mailchimp.com/schema/3.0/CollectionLinks/Batches.json"},{"rel":"self","href":"https://us13.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/batches/af07a55fea","method":"GET","targetSchema":"https://us13.api.mailchimp.com/schema/3.0/Batches/Instance.json"}]}"
```

Which i sadly do not understand fully, why is it pending? I've tried get requests on the id generated, and sadly always said "pending", no matter how long i waited beforehand.

Has anyone encountered the same issue? What can be done to make the above code work?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT 1 : Correction according to the first answer given by TooMuchPete.

Comment: These run one at a time, by the way, so if you have a bunch of them sent in, they'll all be pending until it becomes their turn. If you're not seeing any of the flip away from `pending` you should contact customer support and see what's up.

Comment: I am doing a very a similar operation in node and I am running into the same issue. If you notice the total_operations is 0, and I am not sure why. However I am getting the same thing. I also added the the md5 hash of the email address after members which did not make a difference.

Comment: I think the total_operations: 0 means we're not allowed to make operations, which would explain the trouble we're into, but then it's only a theory. To this date,  my operations don't launch either.

Comment: Well as a temporary fix I was able to make single requests in a forEach loop on the array. Just have to use something like a timeout function to make sure you don't get a bunch of timed out requests. Not ideal nor good practice, but at least got my list populated for now. Still interested in seeing if someone can help with your question though.

Comment: @LamaDelRay Do you think this is a problem on MailChimp's end? I'm having the same issue too.

Comment: @Mikedklein the trouble here is that according to Mailchimp's tutorial we followed, it should be possible to do it like they did. Doing each of the request like you said is by far the closest thing that works. I don't really know if it's supposed to work well like that though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I sent an inquiry into mailchimp API support. The response you are getting is technically ok.

You should poll the url for batches with the batches id that is returned using a get request.

`{"id":"af07a55fea", ...`

Then cancel the polling when the status changes `{"id":"af07a55fea","status":"finished",`

[Link](http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/batches/) to the batches API docs for more clarity. Make sure to reference the read tab for the get request against the batches API.

Comment: So i should do asynchrones check to be sure something happend? Thanks for the answer anyway, i'll try that way!

Comment: I managed to make it work based on what you linked. Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: @mikedklein Is there a quick way to get the id from a previously sent batch request (sort of like [mysql_insert_id](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) command)?

Comment: @mikedklein Can you possibly post an example of polling the url in PHP?

Comment: @goodEgg the id of the batch comes back in the response. I could try and put some PHP code for polling but I think someone more well versed in PHP should I was doing this in Node.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you are putting too much info in the path. From the docs you linked, they start their path after `/3.0/` and yours seems to start with `http://`.

Comment: Editting my code in consequence, it's smoother but still no change on the result so far. Thanks for pointing this error!